# FME and WebDAV resources

Tags: fme-form, data-management, spatial-etl

FME is capable of reading and writing from and to a broad variety of data sources and formats, but is it somehow possible to read/write from/to a *WebDAV* resource with FME?

A cloud storage solution that uses WebDAV for document access, creation etc. can be accessed via file manager like normal directories, but trying to write directly via filemanager fails. Instead one has to write to a filesytem folder and synchronize this folder with the WebDAV ressource with a third party solution (i.e. https://www.goodsync.com)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV

There is a post in the FME knowledge center, but this has not drawn any attention yet (https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/42028/webdav-file-download.html).

Comment: you can call python to get the files from WebDAV https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webdavclient/1.0.8 and use the https://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/pythoncaller.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this probably due to configuration issues? Assuming you are on Windows, usually you can map your webdav resource as a drive in Windows Explorer as e.g. described here https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/windows/map_drive/ (same applies for Win10). Done so, you should be able to read and write to the maped drive as to a normal file system folder.

Be aware, that Windows will remember your credentials for the webdav resource, but does not connect the resource on startup. That means, you have to login to the connected resource, before trying to access it with FME!

Answer (score 0):

Our FME server was not able to read the conted of a mapped webdav. Our alternative is to use a **FME httpCaller** to download the files hosted on the webdav.
We didn't try but theoretically you can upload a file on a webdav in the same way.